# How to determine the build definition that triggered a release in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, release-management, tfvc

Since it's not possible in TFS to have one single build definition to handle the same code in multiple branches when using TFVC, we have to maintain multiple build definitions for our branches.

Now we have extended our CI/CD pipeline to do automated release deployments. Since we have multiple branches, we also have multiple build definitions and now we also have multiple release definitions.

With TFS 2017.1 it's now possible to define multiple Continuous Deployment triggers (artifact sources) in a release definition. If one of the build definitions associated to these artifact sources is successfully built, a new release can automatically be created and deployed.
To be able to get rid of multiple release definitions it would be necessary to determine the build that acutally triggered the creation of a new release and its deployment.

There are a number of variables that can be used in the release definition but unfortunately it does not seem to be possible to get the build/artifact that actually triggered the release (see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables#primary-artifact-variables).

How can the build definition/artifact be determined that triggered the release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I would have preferred a more direct way to find the triggered "{Artifact alias}" of the corresponding build, but the only way I found to determine which build has triggered the release was to get the following environment variable : **$env:RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION**
This variable has the following computed value :
*"Triggered by" + {Artifact alias} + BuildId + "."*
Hope this helps
Best regards
Stéphane

Comment: That's what I found too after sifting through the environment variables. I really don't like the idea of analysing an automatically generated description value, but this seems to be the only way as of today.
So thank you very much for the confirmation.

Comment: This was a great solution for me, and ended up helping solve the problem of seeing what triggered the release when having multiple artifacts in the triggering sources. Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

In the release definition in TFS 2017 Update1, if you bind more than one build definitions to it and add Continuous Deployment triggers for each artifacts in your release definition. Then your release definition will be triggered each time a build succeed.

To know which build triggers your release, you could refer to the **release summary page**.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to get this information in the release definition itself and not only after the release has been deployed, e.g. using a predefined variable or the like?
My goal is to change the path to the build artifact that gets deployed depending on the build that actually triggered the release.

Comment: @Powdermountain99 the release environment variables only provide to get whom trigger the release, doesn't provide which build triggers it. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables#release-environment-variables

Comment: Sorry, take a look to my post. You can find out which build  a release triggered. Take the PowerShell snippet from my post and execute it with the inline function of the MS PowerShell step.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you can use the marked environment variable.

[image]

With this snippet you can get and print all envirnent variable. The screenshot shows the result of executing this snippet.

```
# Get all release environment variables
$environmentVars = get-childitem -path env:*

# Show each environment variable
foreach($var in $environmentVars){
    $keyname = $var.Key
    $keyvalue = $var.Value 
    Write-Verbose "${keyname}: $keyvalue" -Verbose
}
```

Comment: is the environment variable BUILD_BUILDNUMBER not the same as the "Primary artifact variable" "Build.DefinitionName" as described in the Release Management documentation under https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables#primary-artifact-variables? Is it the actual build that triggered or is it only the build name of the primary artifact?

Comment: You can see it on the screenshot, the value of the variable "BUILD_BUILDNUMBER" is the triggered build definition.

Comment: As I mentioned above BUILD_BUILDNUMBER does not contain the build number of the triggering build definition but the build number of the one marked as "primary" in the artifacts list of the release definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement (get the path to the Artifact of the triggering build) but the suggested solution did not work for me - the $env:RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION is blank.

**The cause:** 
This was because the release is manually triggered. We cannot have auto deployment in these builds, a deployment must be manually triggered, as most builds are not deployed. However, the point I was missing is that, while we don't want any of the *Environments* within the build automatically triggered, it is ok for the *Release* to be created automatically.

**The solution:**
Once I understood this, and enabled the CI trigger on each of the artifacts in the Release definition, but kept all of the Environment triggers as "Manual Only", the $env:RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION is now populated, and the approach proposed by "stephgou" will work.

It would be nice if TFS had a better solution for this, as parsing a description is definitely not nice! Ultimately we need the DropLocation, so need this added as a variable also.

Here is my PowerShell script to get the DropLocation from the Description, it may be useful to someone:

```js
#*================================================================================
#* Summary: This is a workaround for a TFS Limitation.
#*          Determines the Drop Location of a vNext build, as it is NOT provided in a variable for us!
#*
#* Output: values will be available in the following Build Step variables:
#*    $(TriggeringBuildID)
#*    $(TriggeringBuildNumber)
#*    $(TriggeringBuildUri)
#*    $(DropLocation)
#* Or, in a script:
#*    $env:TRIGGERINGBUILDID
#*    $env:TRIGGERINGBUILDNUMBER
#*    $env:TRIGGERINGBUILDURL
#*    $env:DROPLOCATION
#*================================================================================


Param (
    [string] $DeploymentScript = "_internalDeployment\DeployBuild_vNext.ps1"
)


$tfsServer=$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI
$teamProject = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT

# Default these, but as we may have multiple build artifacts associated with the release, need to get the triggering build ID if possible.
$script:buildID = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$script:buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$script:buildURI = $env:BUILD_BUILDURI

Write "buildID = $script:buildID"
Write "buildNumber = $script:buildNumber"
Write "buildURI = $script:buildURI"

$ReleaseDescription = $env:RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION
if( $ReleaseDescription -and $ReleaseDescription.Length -gt 16 )
{
    Write "$ReleaseDescription = [$ReleaseDescription], Determining the Triggering Build."

    # This is a work-around for the fact TFS Release does not have any variables for the triggering build ID\Number (only has the Primary Artifact).
    # Hack is to get it from the Release's description, which is populated with trigger information IF it has CI-Trigger enabled.

    $buildChanged = $false

    # Parse the ReleaseDescription. Expected format: "Triggered by <ArtifactAlias> <BuildNumber>."
    # TODO a better way to do this? ... regex.
    $a,$b,$c,$d = $ReleaseDescription.split(' ')
    $TriggeringBuildNumber = $d.Remove($d.Length-1)
    Write "TriggeringBuildNumber = $TriggeringBuildNumber"

    if( $TriggeringBuildNumber -ne $script:buildNumber )
    {
        # Get the BuildId:
        $uri = "$tfsServer/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&buildNumber=$TriggeringBuildNumber"
        Write "Invoking Method : GET $uri"
        $Build = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "$uri"
        if( $Build[0] -and $Build.value -and $Build.value.Count -eq 1 -and $Build.value[0].id -ne 0)
        {
            $script:BuildId = $Build.value[0].id
            $script:buildNumber = $TriggeringBuildNumber    # = $Build.value[0].buildNumber
            $script:buildURI = $Build.value[0].url
            Write  "Build Found - ID is $BuildId."
            $buildChanged = $true
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Build not found"
        }
    }

    if( $buildChanged ) 
    {
        Write "buildID changed to $script:buildID"
        Write "buildNumber changed to $script:buildNumber"
        Write "buildURI changed to $script:buildURI"
    }
}
else
{
    # Allow for manually triggered build (but it has to be the primary artifact for this to work)
    $TriggeringBuildNumber = $script:buildNumber
}


# Determine the DropLocation from the BuildId.
# This is a work-around for the fact TFS Release does not have a variable for the DropLocation.
$BuildId = $script:buildID
Write "Get the DropLocation for buildId = $BuildId"
$DropLocation = ""
$DropLocationRoot = ""

# Get the build's artifacts
$uri = "$tfsServer/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$BuildId/artifacts?api-version=4.1"
Write "Invoking Method : GET $uri"
$artifacts = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "$uri"

# Find the drop location (filepath)
foreach( $artifact in $artifacts.value )
{
    if( $artifact.name -eq $TriggeringBuildNumber -and $artifact.resource -and $artifact.resource.type -eq "filepath" -and  $artifact.resource.data )
    {
        $DropLocationRoot = $artifact.resource.data
        Write  "Artifact Found - DropLocationRoot is $DropLocationRoot."
        Break
    }
}
if( $DropLocationRoot -eq "" )
{ 
    throw "DropLocation not found."
}

$DropLocation = "$DropLocationRoot\$TriggeringBuildNumber"
Write  "DropLocation = $DropLocation"

if( Test-Path $DropLocation )
{
    Write  "Yay! - Drop folder Found at $DropLocation. :-)"
    $DeploymentScript = "$DropLocation\$DeploymentScript"
    if( Test-Path $DeploymentScript )
    {
        Write  "... and Yay, the Deployment Script was Found at $DeploymentScript. :-)"
    }
    else
    {
        throw "... but whoops! - Deployment Script was NOT Found. :-("
    }
}
else
{
    throw "whoops! - DropLocation [$DropLocation] does not exist. :-("
}


# Pass the values back out via $env vars.

# Note: tried using the below to reset the standard TFS System Variables, but it doesn't seem to take effect:
#Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_BUILDID]$script:buildID"
#Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_BUILDNUMBER]$script:buildNumber"
#Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_BUILDURI]$script:buildURI"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TRIGGERINGBUILDID]$script:buildID"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TRIGGERINGBUILDNUMBER]$script:buildNumber"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TRIGGERINGBUILDURI]$script:buildURI"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DROPLOCATION]$DropLocation"
```

Comment: Note: there is a problem with the above script:- of the 4 values I am trying to set at the end, only the DROPLOCATION has a value in the next script executed in the phase. The 3 BUILD_* variables do not get set. I did not notice this initially as only the DROPLOCATION is critical to the next step, until a recent change in which the BUILD_BUILDID became important, so I noticed this issue. So, need to either execute this script from within any other script that needs the values, or set custom variables like my DROPLOCATION to pass to next step.

Comment: Have updated my script to correct passing Build identification values back to caller.